# I want not to escape HTML tags and to use object literal in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie of AngularJS. I want NOT to escape HTML tags, and wrote the code below.

At first, defining `deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnipet()` I succeeded to escape HTML tags (with good advisers in this site).

Secondary, I want to use `<div ng-bind-html="phone.snippet"></div>`.

```
<script>
  angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) { 
    $scope.phone = 
      {'name': 'Nexus S',
       'snippet': '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-RRqZ7FAlG0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'};
    // This works well
    $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-RRqZ7FAlG0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    };
    // This doesn't work
    //$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.article.content);
  }])
</script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>

  <!-- ### Can we write like below? ### -->
  <div ng-bind-html="phone.snippet"></div>

</div>
```

The code is on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATO2EPhIfTeT67u8MAcr?p=preview), too.

Comment: too bad i am on mobile. don't know how to put code tag in mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) { 
        $scope.phone = 
          {'name': 'Nexus S',
           'snippet': '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-RRqZ7FAlG0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'};
        $scope.phone.snippet = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.phone.snippet);

      }])
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>

      <!-- ### Can we write like below? ### -->
      <div ng-bind-html="phone.snippet"></div>

    </div>    
  </body>

</html>
```

another option is add `ngSanitize.js` so you do not need to do `$sce.trustAsHtml`

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `secureHtml` filter. That filter would trust your expression as HTML like this

```
youApp.filter('secureHtml', function ($sce) {
    return function (input) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
  })
```

You could then use the filter in your template like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="harmlessSnippet | secureHtml"></div>
```

Working plunkr with your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/IsW7Q6s4bySp8Eim40kf?p=preview